# Java filter on ajax

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, filter

There is a single page website which for example 10 links to some forms, all of them are reloaded by using ajax(by JSON in rests).

I want to use filter for first link and redirect to another website. I implemented a simply class (extends Filter), check URL and if this is first - redirect to address XXX.

It works when I pass first-form link in browser or open in new tab but doesn't work for ajax requests.

Is there any way to use filter for this kind of requests and get redirect?

Comment: Can you please add some code to your post?